# How to get SolrJ suggester output in JSON format or convert response to POJO

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am very new to Solr/SolrJ. I want to get suggestions for my query, to do so I have created one request handler called "suggest" (I am using following link as reference : Suggester#LookupImplementations). It is providing the correct output, but in beans format, even if I have provided the parameter : query.set("wt", "json"). I need to forward the output of the query to client application. How do I get the response in JSON format or how do I convert the response in some POJO. I am able to do this successfully when I am using default request handler i.e. "select", it provides a response which I am able to convert into POJO as this contains all same fields which I have in Solr schema. Please let me know if you require any additional information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I asked the question at Solr forum and got the way to solve the problem. You can check here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ

Answer (score 0):

Add your suggest handler to the select request handler, then go from there. You will need to do this in `solrconfig.xml` and the configuration will look something like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">dflt</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">spellcheck</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>    
      <str name="field">spellcheck</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">3</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.00001</float>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Comment: I want to use /select and /suggest separately. I do not want to mix the output of search and suggestions.